# jquery best approach to hide elements

Tags: jquery, html, hide

I have 6 divs and trying to hide 5 on click and show 1 div. What would be the best approach to hide 5 divs and show 1 div? I am thinking in a way if I have n number of divs. Need suggestions

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#divLandingLink1').click(function () {
            $('#landingInfo1').show();
            $('#landingInfo2,#landingInfo3,#landingInfo4,#landingInfo5,#landingInfo6').hide();
        });
        $('#divLandingLink2').click(function () {
            $('#landingInfo2').show();
            $('#landingInfo1,#landingInfo3,#landingInfo4,#landingInfo5,#landingInfo6').hide();
        });
        $('#divLandingLink3').click(function () {
            $('#landingInfo3').show();
            $('#landingInfo1,#landingInfo2,#landingInfo4,#landingInfo5,#landingInfo6').hide();
        });
        $('#divLandingLink4').click(function () {
            $('#landingInfo4').show();
            $('#landingInfo1,#landingInfo2,#landingInfo3,#landingInfo5,#landingInfo6').hide();
        });
        $('#divLandingLink5').click(function () {
            $('#landingInfo5').show();
            $('#landingInfo1,#landingInfo2,#landingInfo3,#landingInfo4,#landingInfo6').hide();
        });
        $('#divLandingLink6').click(function () {
            $('#landingInfo6').show();
            $('#landingInfo1,#landingInfo2,#landingInfo3,#landingInfo4,#landingInfo5').hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `data-div` attribute to the links:

```
<div id="container">
    <a href="#" data-div="landingInfo1">Info 1</a>
    <div id="landingInfo1">
        More info here
    </div>
    <a href="#" data-div="landingInfo2">Info 2</a>
    <div id="landingInfo2">
        More info here
    </div>
</div>
```

And then bind the click event to hide all `div`s except the one that was clicked.

```
$("#container > a").click(function(){
    var $div = $("#" + $(this).data("div"));
    $("#container > div").not($div).hide();
    $div.show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var $links = $('#landingInfo1,
                #landingInfo2,
                #landingInfo3,
                #landingInfo4,
                #landingInfo5,
                #landingInfo6')
   .on("click", function(){
      $(this).show();
      $links.not(this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Make all the div's have a common class:

```
$(".option").click(function(){
    $(".option").hide();
    $(this).show();
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PW7Aa/

Answer (score 1):

Since it looks like the divs you are clicking on are different than the ones being hidden/shown, you'll need a way to link the clickable divs with the hide/show ones.  Data attributes in your markup might be a good option for this.

Not knowing your structure, here's a basic example which also gives common classes to the clickable and showable divs for easy access.

```
<div id="divLandingLink1" class="divLandingLink" data-id="landingInfo1">show info div 1</div>
<div id="landingInfo1" class="landingInfo">info div 1</div>
<div id="divLandingLink2" class="divLandingLink" data-id="landingInfo2">show info div 2</div>
<div id="landingInfo2" class="landingInfo">info div 2</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.divLandingLink').click(function () {
            $('.landingInfo').hide();
            var id = $(this).data('id');
            $('#'+id).show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TpgH8/1/

Answer (score 1):

Here's one example, and here's a <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/sLxDQ/)**</kbd>

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li data-rel="1">Info 1
    </li><li data-rel="2">Info 2
    </li><li data-rel="3">Info 3
    </li><li data-rel="4">Info 4
    </li><li data-rel="5">Info 5
    </li><li data-rel="6">Info 6</li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="info">Content 1</div>
<div class="info">Content 2</div>
<div class="info">Content 3</div>
<div class="info">Content 4</div>
<div class="info">Content 5</div>
<div class="info">Content 6</div>
```

---

```
nav ul {
  margin: 10px 20px;
  list-style: none;
}
nav li {
  background: #ddd;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.info {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  top: 50px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px dotted #ddd;
}
.info:nth-of-type(1) {
  display: block;
}
```

---

```
$(function() {
  $('nav li').click(function() {
    $('.info:nth-of-type('+$(this).data('rel')+')').fadeIn(400).siblings('.info').fadeOut(400);
  });
});
```